# the way to restart the double loop in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm looking for the way to restart nested loop in java
basically that is what I'm thinking:

```
for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
  for(int j = 0;j < value2;j++) {
     if(condition) {
        i=-1;
        break;
     }
     //some code here
     }
    }
```

But maybe you can suggest something better?

Comment: Use a function and restart is as many times as you want.

Comment: This looks simple enough. You can use a label but thats more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use loop labels.

```
 OUTER: for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
          for(int j = 0;j < value2;j++) {
             if(condition) {
                continue OUTER;
              }
           //some code here
         }
       }
```

Comment: This doesn't restart the loop i.e. with `i==0`

Comment: Add `i = -1` before `continue` and it will be right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void ExampleLoop(boolean isStarted)
{
    while(isStarted)
    {
        if(condition)
        {
            isStarted = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in main:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.ExampleLoop(true);
//Or stop with:
myClass.ExampleLoop(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions?

```
class Ideone
{

    static Runnable r;
    static boolean brokeOnce = false;


    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        r = () ->  { 
            firstloop: for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
                System.out.println(i + " " + j);
                if (!brokeOnce && i == 1 && j == 1) {
                    brokeOnce = true;
                    r.run();
                    break firstloop;
                }
              }
            }
        };

        r.run();
    }
}
```

Ideone link: http://ideone.com/EqPEJ6

Comment: Too simple. I think we need more complicated example of using `for()`.

Comment: You're right. I should be using more interfaces and abstract classes as well as my own extension of Runnable. :)